Get From Session in .NET
This is my methods for get session and save in. I set session method in correct way and write service in IOC:
service.AddHttpContextAccessor();

 public List<CartItemViewModel> GetFromSession()
 {
     var result = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<CartItemViewModel>>("ses-basket");

     if (result == null)
     {
         return new List<CartItemViewModel>();
     }

     return result;
 }

 // or return result ?? new List<CartItemViewModel>();

 // Save data in session
 public void SaveInSession(CartItemViewModel item)
 {
     var cart = GetFromSession();

     int index = cart.FindIndex(m => m.ChefFoodId == item.ChefFoodId);

     if (index != -1)
     {
         cart[index].Quantity += 1;
     }
     else
     {
         cart.Add(new CartItemViewModel()
                      {
                          Quantity = item.Quantity,
                          ChefFoodId = item.ChefFoodId,
                          FoodTitle = item.FoodTitle,
                          ChefFoodsPrice = item.ChefFoodsPrice,
                          ImageFood = item.ImageFood
                      });
     }

     _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("ses-basket", cart);
 }

I get correct date from repository, and I see correct data in breakpoint, but however I get data correctly and with correct setting for session method and in program.cs -  GetFromSession method always returns null. Why?
 public async Task<CartItemViewModel> GetItemByChefFoodId(int chefFoodId)
 {
     var weekdayFood = await _context.WeekDayFoods
         .Where(wfd => wfd.IsActive)
         .Where(wfd => wfd.IsActive)
         .Include(wfd => wfd.ChefFood)
         .ThenInclude(wfd => wfd.Food)
         .Include(wfd => wfd.ChefFood)
         .ThenInclude(wfd => wfd.ChefFoodPrices)
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.ChefFoodId == chefFoodId);

     if (weekdayFood != null)
     {
         return new CartItemViewModel
         {
             ChefFoodId = weekdayFood.ChefFoodId,
             FoodTitle = weekdayFood.ChefFood.Food.FoodTitle,
             ChefFoodsPrice = weekdayFood.ChefFood.ChefFoodPrices.Any() ? weekdayFood.ChefFood.ChefFoodPrices.FirstOrDefault().ChefFoodsPrice : 0,
             ImageFood = weekdayFood.ChefFood.Food.ImageFood,
             Quantity = 1 // مقدار پیش‌فرض برای یک آیتم جدید
         };
     }
     else
     {
          return null;
     }
 }

